# How can I use Selenium's getText() on partial text?

Tags: selenium, gettext

When I'm using the `getText()` method on the next web class, I'm getting the full text associated with it:

```
$('.row.session-panel.form-group .session-name [href]')[0]

<a href=​"/​10002267/​agenda/​session/​10020933">​"8:30am - 9:45am "<span>​Welcoming Notes​</span>​</a>​
```

If I use the `getText()` I'm getting the full
text: **"8:30am - 9:45am Welcoming Notes"**. Is there a way getting only the **8:30am - 9:45am** without applying Java's special methods like `substring()`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is just the text which is directly represented by the text nodes in your `a` element. There is currently no method in Selenium that allows to get the text of an element without also getting the text of its children. You can do the following to extract the text from the DOM directly.

```java
String text = (String) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
    "var parent = arguments[0]; "+
    "var child = parent.firstChild; "+
    "var ret = ""; "+
    "while(child) { "+
    "    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) "+
    "        ret += child.textContent; "+
    "    child = child.nextSibling; "+
    "} "+
    "return ret;", a);
```

(It's been a while since I've coded on Java on a regular basis. This is converted from Python code. There may be a nicer way to represent it.)

The variable `a` would be the anchor you've already found using one of Selenium's methods for finding elements. If you need something finer (e.g. remove spaces or any other extraneous character you don't want) and somehow cannot do it on the Java side, you could add it to the code above on the JavaScript side. For instance you could have `return ret.trim()` if you want to get rid of leading and trailing space.

I've used the method above on Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer 10-11 without problems. I do not see anything there that is not covered by the most basic levels of DOM so I would expect it to work on any browser.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use substring().

Answer (score 0):

The DOM structure inside the `<a>` forbids you to use jQuery functions to manipulate the DOM easily.

```
var fullTxt = $('.row.session-panel.form-group .session-name [href]')[0].getText()
var spanTxt = $('.row.session-panel.form-group .session-name [href] > span')[0].getText();
var finalTxt = fullTxt.replace(spanTxt,"")
```

If you can't use `substring()`, you can't use `split('"')[1]` as well I guess.