# Creating a Selenium getText() method for an element?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to create a Selenium getText() method that gets either the node text OR gets the node+child text of an element.   By default, the Selenium behavior seems to use the Xpath .//string() method of getting text and including the text of immediate children.   I want to take advantage of XPaths power to enable me to get the text in a more targeted way.  My question is: **am I misunderstanding this or is there a better way to accomplish this?**

```
public String getText(By locationOfText, boolean childText)
{
  By locator = null;
  if ( childText)
  {
    locator = ByChained( locationOfText, By.xpath(".//string()"));
  } else {
    locator = ByChained( locationOfText, By.xpath(".//text()"));
  }
  JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  String elementText = jse.executeScript("document.evaluate(locator, document.body, null, 
     XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null);");

  return elementText;
}
```

Here is an HTML snippet:

```
<h5 class="class-name clearfix">Inner Text
   <a class="info-link class-description" href="#">i</a>
</h5>
```

The problem is that I get the text **Inner Texti** when I use Selenium to do a text call like this:

```
driver.findElement(".//h5").getText();
```

My expectation was to retrieve the value **Inner Text** .  By creating the method above, I hope to call it like so:

```
String text = elementHelper.getText(By.xpath(".//h5"),false);
```

Comment: Could you add more on the motivational side of the question? Also, can you provide an example HTML? Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe -  Ok, I added more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string()` is an XPath 2.0 construct but most browsers (if not all), only support XPath 1.0. Moreover, I'm not that fond of rushing to XPath for querying the DOM tree. XPath evaluation has a significant performance overhead. So [adapting my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26157880/selenium-how-to-use-gettext-on-partial-text/26159175#26159175), I would suggest:

```
public String getText(By locationOfText, boolean childText)
{
  WebElement el = driver.findElement(locationOfText);
  if (childText)
  {
    return el.getText();
  }

  JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  return jse.executeScript(
    "var parent = arguments[0]; "+
    "var child = parent.firstChild; "+
    "var ret = ""; "+
    "while(child) { "+
    "    if (child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) "+
    "        ret += child.textContent; "+
    "    child = child.nextSibling; "+
    "} "+
    "return ret;", el);
}
```

The `locationOfText` parameter could be any `By` method that Selenium supports.

In your code you use `ByChained` for `location`, which presumably you'd want to pass to `executeScript` but forgot to do. I cannot see how this would work, even if you added `location` to your `executeScript` call (and fixed the script to grab `arguments[0]`). `ByChained` would support things like mixing a CSS selector with an XPath, etc. *Selenium* can presumably resolve the combination by performing multiple searches but there is no way the XPath engine of a browser will accept some sort of combination of CSS and XPath.